# add a counter of the length of documents of a collection in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an ecommerce where I use react in the front end and firebase/firestore in the backend.
I managed to add/delete products and I stored them in a collection that belongs to the each user. What I want to do is to have a counter in the navbar, and in other components, that indicates the number of documents (products) that the user that's login has in the basket, but because of the scope, I cannot manage to do it.

In products.js

```
    const addToBasket = () => {
        db.collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection('basket').add({productId: id, title: title, 
        cont: content, img: image, price: price})
    }
```

In checkoutProduct.js

```
    const removeFromBasket = () => {          
     firestore().collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection('basket').doc(id.toString()).delete();
    }
```

In checkout.js

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if(user){
        firestore().collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection('basket').get().then(snapshot => {
            setProducts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id} }))
        })    
    }
    }, [])
```

Comment: Do you want a component which visualises number of items in the basket and then reuse that component in several places? Or do you want just to have data to visualise in several different places?

Comment: yeah the second option, i wanna have data to visualize in different places

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of documents from the [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) that is returned from `get()`:

```
firestore().collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection('basket').get().then(snapshot => {
    setProducts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id} }))
    setCartItemCount(snapshot.size); // <== this is the new line
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common thing that needs to be handled on the frontend.
One solution for you is to store the information in a context.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Conceptually, one thing you can do is to update that context whenever a successful write has been made to the database, in your case Firestore.

So, that way you update your frontend as the backend updates.
This can be done with an observer on your snapshot.

Read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score 0):

As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14547938/daniel) said there are many ways to solve this problem. So lets elaborate a bit on his useContext proposal. They way I handle Firebase in my apps, I have a single class for the Firebase, because it should be a singleton:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);

    this.db = app.database();
    this.auth = app.auth();
  }

  // *** Auth API ***
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

  signInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

  signOut = () => this.auth.signOut();

  sendPasswordResetEmail = email => this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);

  updatePassword = password => this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password);

  onAuthUserListener = (next, fallback) =>
    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user(user.uid)
          .once("value")
          .then(snapshot => {
            const dbUser = snapshot.val();

            if (!dbUser.roles) {
              dbUser.roles = {};
            }

            next({
              uid: user.uid,
              email: user.email,
              ...dbUser
            });
          });
      } else {
        fallback();
      }
    });

  // *** User API ***
  user = uid => this.db.ref(`/users/${uid}`);

  users = () => this.db.ref(`users`);
}

export default Firebase;
```

Then I would create a context for it:

```
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);
```

There are many ways how that context can be used, either with useContext, or with FirebaseContext.Provider/Consumer

I usually wrap my app in FirebaseProvider:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
        <App />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

After that, anywhere within my component's tree I can use that context with a consumer or with useContext:

```
function BasketCount() {
    const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.firestore.collection('users').doc(user?.uid).collection('basket').get().then(snapshot => {
            setCount(snapshot.size); // <== this is the new line
        })   
    }, [firebase])

    return (
        <>{count}</>
    )
}
```

You are more than welcome to take a look at this [skeleton](https://github.com/PompolutZ/react-firebase-auth-skeleton) to see more things in context.